# how can i loop through the returned JSON using Httpclient

Tags: java, httpclient

I have the following code for calling an API that returns JSON with the following format:-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      " Ser": 1,
      " No": 1
    },
    {
      " Ser": 2,
      " No": 2
    },
    {
      " Ser": 3,
      " No": 3
    },
    {
      " Ser": 4,
      " No": 4
    },
    {
      " Ser": 5,
      " No": 5
    },

  ]
}
```

The code is:-

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/json/api/getinfo?type=100");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
// Get the response, how i can loop through the returned JSON and assign the reterned json to a global parameters which i can access from ym system using has values #parameter1# , #parameter2#, etc.
```

so how can I loop through the returned JSON and assign it 'NO' to the global parameters?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should get the content out of the `HttpReponse` object through the `HttpEntity.getContent()` as mentioned in the [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html). The content should then be fed to a `JSONObject` from any JSON library like the one from [json.org/java](http://json.org/java/). Then you can traverse the JSON output through the `JSONObject` and extract elements out of it.

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) 
{
    //
    // Using Commons IO library's IOUtils method 
    // to read the content from the stream.
    //
    String json = IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent());
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    // Process the JSON

    // shutdown the connection.
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but is there an example or tutorial that can help me .

Comment: The example from HttpClient documentation page will help you get the JSON content. Then, based on the JSON library you decide to use, it would have sample examples to convert a String to JSONObject and how traverse it. So, I am not sure if there would be a single tutorial/example covering both.